# How to configure IAM Role with AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and c# to make an Alexa skill and I think I'm stuck on a configuration issue.
Alexa Developer Console returns **"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"** to the invocation request.
The logs record errors **"Skill execution returned an exception for requestId"** and **"An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."**

The skill itself is supposed to return the phrase "test" and uploads with name PCFunction to the Europe(London) region. The skill did work briefly and I haven't changed it so that part I think is fine.

I've changed the assembly attribute from **Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer** to **Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer** as I read that had been a problem for a few.

I've updated the handler to **"MyComputer::MyComputer.Function::FunctionHandler"** from what's shown in the image and checked the assembly name is correct so the format of that is good I think.

[image]

Visual studio is configured to PCUser  with the same region and shows the function in the list under AWS Lambda.

[image]

The user has blanket AdminAccess permissions.

[image]

The role has logs and lambda perms and I've manually checked lambda.amazonaws.com is allowed and in there.

[image]

The function itself has Alexa added as a trigger and shows that the role is connected.

[image]

Plus finally, the endpoint is copied/pasted directly from the function page so shouldn't have any errors.

[image]

What am I missing? I've deleted Functions, Users, Roles and Visual Studio credentials several times and started from scratch ending up in the same place so unlikely it's some obscure setting I've accidentally changed.
I've also left it a good hour after making changes for them to reflect across servers so I don't think not waiting long enough was an issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly started working again. I think the problem was IAM Roles can take several hours to update when changes are made and I simply didn't wait long enough after making edits.
About 6 hours since I last touched it.